# Flutter disable Column's Widget shrink (CircleAvatar)

Tags: flutter

I have a `CircleAvatar` Widget inside a `Column`. For some reason the `CircleAvatar` shrinks when not specifying the radius.

Why is that? And how do I get a `CircleAvatar` that uses **max space** in the `Column`?

My Code:

```
Column(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          //radius: 33,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              child: Text(
                "Profile Name",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
          child: Text("Text),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

With radius:
[image]

Without radius:
[image]

Comment: When not specifying the `radius` of `CircleAvatar` it defaults to 20 logical pixels, which is > 33, that's why you think it shrinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that works is to wrap your `Column` widget in a `SizedBox` and set both the width and height property to `double.infinity`. And then wrap your `CircleAvatar` with `Expanded` widget and set the `radius` property of the `CircleAvatar` to double.infinity.

```
SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Expanded(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: double.infinity,
               child: ...,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
            child: Text("Text"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: double.infinity,
               child: ...,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
            child: Text("Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And @esentis is right, the radius property of a CircleAvatar has a default value - as it is with some other properties of Widgets, When you don't specify the property with your own value, it defaults to the original value.